# Data not getting added on Firebase until i close my app and open again

Tags: java, firebase, asynchronous, firebase-realtime-database

I'm handling the transaction in background service. Everything was working until this January. Every time i push to firebase, log response before and after pushing, **I discovered that it is not pushing the update to firebase until i close my app and open it again**.

Below is the simple thing that is not working

```
    private void updateAllBlog(final Uri fileUri, final String user_id, final String checker,
                           Map<String, Object> userMap, final DatabaseReference share_blog) {

    Log.d(TAG, "updateAllBlog ,"+ userMap);
    share_blog.updateChildren(userMap).addOnSuccessListener(task -> {

        Log.d(TAG, "Completed Update,1"+ userMap);
        final String blog_key = share_blog.getKey();

        Log.d("Blog_id", blog_key);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase already updated documentation on how to handle upload and getting the download url. Since no way i could know than to check documentation again and follow it step by step.

Here is the updated link
https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files